# Should I prune my Autumn-fruiting raspberries?

Tags: pruning, raspberries

I have autumn fruiting raspberries (Autumn Bliss) which I planted in late spring. The original fruit canes have just made a very small crop, but the old canes are yellowing and beginning to wither, while new shoots have come up. I have read that autumn raspberries should be pruned in late winter. Should I cut back the old canes, or just leave them alone?

Answer (score 7):

We've grown Autumn Bliss for years - it's a great variety!

Yes, you should be able to prune now.  Once a cane has fruited and you have taken all the fruit you want from it, cut it down to near the ground. It will not fruit properly again, and will probably die on its own over the winter anyway, so you aren't really losing anything, especially once the new tips start to emerge.  Leaving the old canes till spring just crowds the new ones and allows pests and disease to overwinter, which you do not want. So remove them and either burn them or compost them, but don't leave them hanging around your new shoots.